# How can I git clone without a proxy?

Tags: git

I am on Ubuntu and am trying to git clone some packages off arago-project.org
However, I do not seem to be able to do this. My laptop is connected via WiFi to my home wireless router.

```
carson@carson-laptop:~/oe$ git clone git://arago-project.org/git/arago.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/carson/oe/arago/.git/
```

It just does nothing after that...

Some googling reveals that some people use a proxy. However, is this really necessary? And if so, what proxy do I use in that case?

UPDATE: waited for longer and got this error

```
carson@carson-laptop:~/oe$ git clone git://arago-project.org/git/arago.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/carson/oe/arago/.git/
2011/01/09 10:00:14 socat[4024] E connect(3, AF=2 150.229.98.44:8080, 16): Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
carson@carson-laptop:~/oe$
```

Comment: try to specify error message in the question.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just have some sort of network problem? This works fine for me too, and a timeout is, well, a timeout.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to clone using the git protocol.  The git protocol runs on TCP port 9418 by default, and you are cloning arago-project.org.  Therefore, we'd expect to see a connection to IP address 184.73.161.183 on port 9418.

However, your error message reports an error to 150.229.12.128 port 8080.  This is likely some sort of proxy running on www.csiro.au.  You'll have to investigate things on your end to see if you can avoid that proxy.

If you can't, perhaps you can clone over HTTP.  It's not as efficient as the git protocol, but if should get the job done.  Just run: `git clone http://arago-project.org/git/arago.git`

Comment: I was unable to clone over http ... timeouts.  git protocol still worked just fine for me

Comment: I was playing around with proxies weeks ago trying to get this to work. However, I thought I had removed them all (it still didn't work), exporting http_proxy to nothing.

Comment: The http line works fine for me.  I think you have some network issues that go beyond git.  Can you run "host arago-project.org" and verify that the IP address is reported correctly?  The most full-proof way I can think to clone is to run "env -i git clone http:// 184.73.161.183/git/arago.git" -- it uses an empty environment, IP address of the server, and runs over HTTP.  If that times out, too, you must have an issue in your network infrastructure, and I'm afraid we probably won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clone with no issue, under the same wifi situation.
What version of Git are you using?

```
Waffles:~ clint$ git --version
git version 1.7.3.4

Waffles:~ clint$ git clone git://arago-project.org/git/arago.git
Cloning into arago...
remote: Counting objects: 10763, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8624/8624), done.
remote: Total 10763 (delta 7052), reused 3038 (delta 1808)
Receiving objects: 100% (10763/10763), 7.83 MiB | 740 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7052/7052), done.
```

http://arago-project.org/wiki/index.php/Proxy_Settings 
This wiki page for the Arago project mentions setting up proxy settings, did you try this?

Comment: my git version is 1.7.0.4 though i do not know how to update it. I tried updating via apt-get of git-core, but the git version does not change to 1.7.3.4